# Error when adding product via admin

Tags: magento2

When adding a product via the admin I'm getting the error below:

```
Can't create directory /home/dorodo/staging/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/CreateHandler/. in [Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler\Interceptor]
```

It looks like a write issue. When trying to change the permissions as my user I get "permission denied." Since MageMojo doesn't offer root access and I'm not a part of sudoers is there a workaround or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to my hosting provider. They don't provide root or sudoers for your user. They reset all of my permissions. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete var/generation folder, and delete generated folder, give full permission to pub, and var folders, it may help you